# Language Pack didn't install dictionary for spell check for office 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, language, spell-check, language-pack

I downloaded the language pack for Portuguese, but in word when I try to do the spell check it says the dictionary isn't installed.  When it go to languages in options it shows that Portuguese is there with spell checking.  How do I get word to access the dictionary to it can auto check at run the spell check on Portuguese?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you will need to buy the Portuguese dictionary for Word (I assume you have the English version of Word) See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-word/how-can-i-download-portuguese-spell-checker-to-use/944d0c02-ccfa-4b9f-9bf0-4212f1d5cf3f

Comment: Yup. If you scroll through the About box, you'll notice that Microsoft doesn't actually write most of the proofing tools.

Comment: So in addition to the Portuguese language pack I bought from Microsoft that said it includes Portuguese proofing tools I need to buy a separate dictionary from another source?